# AWS Redshift UNPIVOT boolean columns to category values

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table on Redshift with multiple columns with bool and null values as following

```
| email    | car | house  |
| -------- | ----- | ---  |
| 1@gm.com | true  |false |
| 2@gm.com |       | true |
| 3@gm.com | false |      |
| 4@gm.com |       |      |
| 5@gm.com | true  | true |
```

I would like to unpivot car and house columns and just count when the value is true, as follows

```
| email    | category |
| ---------| -------- |
| 1@gm.com | car      |
| 2@gm.com | house    |
| 5@gm.com | car      |
| 5@gm.com | house    |
```

I know that it would be more easy if I create an script in any programming language and do the process, but I'm not sure if is possible to do something like that using Redshift queries for processing data.

Comment: I think you just want a CASE statement.  A WHERE clause can remove the rows where both boolean values are false or NULL.